# Windows 10 исчезли файлы и папки на рабочем столе, при этом появились файлы из 2019 года и ранее

Tags: windows-10

Сегодня днем, часа в 15:00 у меня обновился Windows 10 Home, компьютер перезагрузился и после включения пропали папки и файлы с конца 2019 года и появились файлы из начала 2019 и более ранние. Учетная запись не поменялась, дополнительных учетных записей нет.
То что из интернета узнал не помогает (В диспетчере задач создавал новую задачу, смотрел реестр и т.д.) Если есть программы точечного (только рабочий стол) восстановления утерянных файлов, можете пожалуйста скинуть названия или ссылки (желательно бесплатных), а может и более легкие способы есть ?
И да, файлы кажется пропали не только с рабочего стола, но и с некоторых дисков(у меня их 3), но так как там нет особо важных файлов это не особо важно, главное рабочий стол восстановить.

Comment: Посмотри версии файлов и точки восстановления системы.

Comment: @Qwertiy в разделе восстановления все пусто, ранее тоже проверял уже.